# How to add and sort items in QComboBox

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qcombobox

I want to (in this analogical example) change QLabel's color by QPushButton click or select it from QComboBox representing the selection history. In real code there are more controls than one button, so there is a method `setColor(self, color)` that adds new color to the QComboBox as its first item, removes possible duplicates and changes the QLabel's color. This works.

The second option is to choose the color from the history QComboBox. I catch event when an item is `pressed` and call the same `setColor(self, color)`. This cause a problem.

Problem is when there are colors in QComboBox e.g. `['red', 'blue', 'green']` I choose option `'blue'` and the order of items is changed to `['blue', 'red', 'green']` (I still want this), there is some standard QComboBox behavior which finishes selection and the QComboBox selects `'green'` item. So, QLabel has correct color, but QComboBox does not have the correct text.

How can I overwrite the "standard behavior" and fix this? Please try this example:

```
import sys
from random import random

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QComboBox, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLabel


class MyCombo(QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.view().pressed.connect(self.handleItemPressed)

    def handleItemPressed(self, index):
        color = self.model().itemData(index)[0]
        self.parent().setColor(color)

    def removeDuplicates(self):
        unique = list()
        while len(unique) < self.model().rowCount():
            if self.itemText(len(unique)) in unique:
                self.removeItem(len(unique))
            else:
                unique.append(self.itemText(len(unique)))


class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)
        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.cmb = MyCombo(self)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Random', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.pnl = QLabel(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.cmb)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.pnl)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.cmb.insertItem(0, color)
        self.cmb.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.cmb.removeDuplicates()
        self.pnl.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % color)

    def btnClicked(self):
        colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange']
        self.setColor(colors[int(random() * len(colors))])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = Gui()
    g.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use the view's `pressed` signal instead of `currentIndexChanged` of QComboBox?

Comment: I want to avoid the cycle reference: When I call `setColor` from `btnClicked` the index is changed and fire `currentIndexChanged` which calls again `setColor` because when is changed by selecting item the `currentIndexChanged` is fired and have to call `setColor` to process all changes. Or is there better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearranging items during operations that include setting the current index is never a good thing, unless you're sure about keeping track of the correct index **and** know the sequence of operations that happen in between.

In your case, the problem is that the `pressed` signal of the view is handled *before* the current index of the combo box is changed, and the result is that when the mouse button is *released* the current index is wrong also due to the reordering of items.

Your implementation also has another problem: keyboard and mouse wheel navigation will not correctly update the color.

My suggestion is to leave the model unchanged (unless a new color is added), and reorder it *only* right before showing the popup.

In order to avoid recursion, always remember that you can block the signals of an object by using [`blockSignals()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals).

```
class MyCombo(QComboBox):
    colorChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.emitChangedColor)

    def emitChangedColor(self, index):
        if index >= 0:
            self.colorChanged.emit(self.itemText(index))

    def setColor(self, color):
        blocked = self.blockSignals(True)
        for index in range(self.count()):
            if self.itemText(index) == color:
                break
        else:
            index = 0
            self.insertItem(index, color)
        self.setCurrentIndex(index)
        self.blockSignals(blocked)

    def showPopup(self):
        if self.currentIndex() > 0:
            blocked = self.blockSignals(True)
            current = self.currentText()
            self.removeItem(self.currentIndex())
            self.insertItem(0, current)
            self.setCurrentIndex(0)
            self.blockSignals(blocked)
        super().showPopup()


class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)
        lay = QVBoxLayout()
        self.cmb = MyCombo(self)
        self.cmb.colorChanged.connect(self.setColor)
        self.btn = QPushButton('Random', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.pnl = QLabel(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.cmb)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.pnl)
        self.setLayout(lay)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self.cmb.setColor(color)
        self.pnl.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % color)

    def btnClicked(self):
        colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'orange']
        self.setColor(colors[int(random() * len(colors))])
```

Answer (score 2):

With a logic similar to the other answer but focusing on the functionality of inserting and removing duplicates, the QComboBox has to do it and only send the information to the window when the item is selected. Also, instead of passing the name, the QColor can be passed as an additional data.

```py
import sys
import random

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QWidget,
    QComboBox,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QPushButton,
    QLabel,
)


class ColorComboBox(QComboBox):
    colorChanged = pyqtSignal(str, QColor)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.handleCurrentIndexChanged)

    def handleCurrentIndexChanged(self, index):
        key = self.itemText(index)
        color = self.itemData(index)
        self.colorChanged.emit(key, color)

    def addColor(self, key, color):
        index = self.findText(key)
        if index != -1:
            self.removeItem(index)
        self.insertItem(0, key, color)
        self.setCurrentIndex(0)


class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.cmb = ColorComboBox()
        self.btn = QPushButton("Random")
        self.pnl = QLabel()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.cmb)
        lay.addWidget(self.btn)
        lay.addWidget(self.pnl)

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btnClicked)
        self.cmb.colorChanged.connect(self.updateColor)

    def btnClicked(self):
        colors = [
            ("red", QColor("red")),
            ("green", QColor("green")),
            ("blue", QColor("blue")),
            ("yellow", QColor("yellow")),
            ("orange", QColor("orange")),
        ]

        key, color = random.choice(colors)
        self.cmb.addColor(key, color)

    def updateColor(self, key, color):
        self.pnl.setStyleSheet('background-color: %s' % color.name())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    g = Gui()
    g.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Nice solution. BTW the `index` in `handleCurrentIndexChanged` may be `-1`, so it's good to handle it.